# Adding a row vector to multiple rows of a matrix, with duplicate row index

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

Suppose we have a matrix

```
A = [1,2;3,4;5,6] 
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

I know that matlab allows adding vector to multiple rows, for example,

```
A([1,2],:) = A([1,2],:) + [1,1];
```

then

```
A =
    2 3
    4 5
    5 6
```

However, A([1,2,1],:) + [1,1] gives the same result

```
A([1,2,1],:) = A([1,2,1],:) + [1,1];
```

then

```
A =
    2 3
    4 5
    5 6
```

This is NOT what I want. The **desired effect** is adding [1,1] to the first row twice, and the expected result is,

```
A([1,2,1],:) = A([1,2,1],:) + [1,1];
```

and A should be

```
A =
    3 4
    4 5
    5 6
```

How do I achieve this? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be achieved with fancy indexing. Matlab will first evaluate the right hand side, which for `A([1,2,1],:) + [1,1];` is

```
2 3
4 5
2 3
```

and then assign it to the matrix on the left. Indices are processed in order, so at first, A(1, :) gets replaced with [2 3], then A(2, :) gets replaced with [4 5], then A(1, :) gets replaced with [2 3] *again* (a waste of time).  In no way can the newly-assigned value of A be immediately used again on the right hand side of the same assignment.

Instead, if you have to start with a list of indexes that has repetitions, the following will work:

```
ix = [1 2 1]
uix = unique(ix)
counts = hist(ix, uix)
A(uix, :) = A(uix, :) + counts' * [1 1]
```

This results in

```
A =    
   3   4
   4   5
   5   6
```